# How to insert insets to data circles in iOS charts

Tags: ios, ios-charts

[image of line chart with insets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiSUo.png)

The readme of iOS Charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) shows a line chart that has insets for the most left and the most right circle (see image above). I can't find any way to achieve this in my chart. Even the charts demo app doesn't have those insets. Any hint how to get those insets into a linechart?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
myChart.xAxis.spaceMin = 10
myChart.xAxis.spaceMax = 4
```

Comment: No, that doesn't help as is moves the data circle *and* the chart itself.

Comment: I guess it is just a zoom then, because if the curve continues after the last visible dot, it must be to get to another dot which is out of the visible chart.